# Getting data from JSON file using axios, but getting Module build failed error

Tags: reactjs, json, axios

I want to place the data from my JSON file onto the webpage, however I get an error:
[Module build failed: Error: ENOENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwSa0.jpg)

This is my directory structure
The React component I'm using is in the pages folder, the pages folder is in the src folder, and the data.json file is in the src folder. Here's an image:
[File directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTbtC.jpg)

This is my react code, you can ignore the in code comments:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import articles from './article-content';
import allarticles from './data.json'
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';

const ArticlePage = () => {
// create a state variables which will be initialized when the app loads from the server
const [articleInfo, setArticleInfo] = useState({ upvotes: 0, comments: []}); 
const { name } = useParams(); //short hand by using object destructuring
const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');
const [text, setText] = useState('');


useEffect(() => {
    const loadArticleInfo = async () => {
        try{
            // `/articles/${name}`
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3005/articletext");
            setArticleInfo(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
        }catch (err){
            console.log(err);
        }

    }
    loadArticleInfo();
   
}, [name]);

const addUpvote = async () => {
    // `/articles/${name}/upvotes`
    const response = await axios.put('http://localhost:3005/articles/upvote',{...articleInfo, upvotes : articleInfo.upvotes+1});
    const updatedArticle = response.data;
    setArticleInfo(updatedArticle);
}

const addComment = async() => {
    const temp_comments = [...articleInfo.comments,{author: author,text: text}];
    // `/articles/${name}/comments`
    const response = await axios.put('http://localhost:3005/articles/comments', {...articleInfo, comments: temp_comments});
    setArticleInfo({...articleInfo, comments: response.data.comments});
    setAuthor('');
    setText('');
}

const url = 'http://localhost:3005/articletext'


const matchingArticle = allarticles.find(article => 
    article.name === name,
    ); // now we have access to the actual content of the matching article containing title, content and name.  These can now be accessed and returned to the view below        

    if (!matchingArticle) {
        return <NotFoundPage />;
    }

return (
    <>
        <h1>This is the article page</h1>
        <h1>{matchingArticle.title}</h1>
        <div id="upvotes-section">
            <button onClick={addUpvote}>Add Upvote</button>
            <p>This article has {articleInfo.upvotes} upvotes</p>
        </div>
        {matchingArticle.content.map(paragraph => (
            <p key={`${paragraph}`}>  {paragraph}   </p> //
        )
        )} 

        <div id="add-comment-form">
            <h3>Add a comment</h3>
            <label htmlFor='commentAuthor'>Name: </label>
            <input value={author}onChange={e => setAuthor(e.target.value)} id='commentAuthor' />
           
            <label htmlFor='commentText'>Comment: </label>                    
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} id='commentText'></textarea>
            
            <button onClick={addComment}>add comment</button>
        </div>
        {/* <h3>Comments</h3>
        {articleInfo.comments.map(comment => (
            <div  key={`${comment.text}`} className="comment"> 
                <h4>{comment.author}</h4>
                <p>{comment.text}</p>
            </div>
        ))} */}


    </>
)
}

export default ArticlePage;
```

And the json file, just in case:

```
{
"articles": [
{
  "upvotes": 2,
  "comments": [],
  "id": "learn-react"
},
{
  "id": "learn-node",
  "upvotes": 7,
  "comments": [
    {
      "author": "anon",
      "text": "Node really changed things for me since I no longer have to master PHP... JS all the way!"
    },
    {
      "author": "Tester",
      "text": "No!!! Not another server!"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "my-thoughts-on-resumes",
  "upvotes": 6,
  "comments": [
    {
      "author": "dabsalom",
      "text": "Really useful tips! I Never thought about resumes this much"
    },
    {
      "author": "Tester",
      "text": "I haven't redone my resume in aeons so this is really helpful"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "jOBJcGY",
  "upvotes": 0,
  "comments": []
}
],
"articletext": [
{
  "name": "learn-react",
  "title": "The Fastest Way to Learn React",
  "content": [
    "(This Works)Welcome! Today we're going to be talking about the fastest way tolearn React. We'll be discussing some topics such as ed eget nisi gravida, faucibus risus vitae, sollicitudin lectus. Aliquam mauris leo, pulvinar eget sapien non, mollis pretium enim. Donec mi sapien, aliquam at aliquam at, ullamcorper sit amet risus. Etiam leo justo, imperdiet id sem et, egestas maximus tellus. Nam a efficitur enim, ac ullamcorper elit. Donec nulla urna, lobortis eu purus ut, malesuada dignissim risus. Donec vel quam quis neque vestibulum lacinia nec ac massa. Curabitur vitae rhoncus erat. Nam a risus sed magna iaculis gravida ut non diam. Mauris non molestie ex. Nam nec volutpat ligula. Duis vitae facilisis diam, et hendrerit lorem. Nullam et luctus metus.ed eget nisi gravida, faucibus risus vitae, sollicitudin lectus. Aliquam mauris leo, pulvinar eget sapien non, mollis pretium enim. Donec mi sapien, aliquam at aliquam at, ullamcorper sit amet risus. Etiam leo justo, imperdiet id sem et, egestas maximus tellus. Nam a efficitur enim, ac ullamcorper elit. Donec nulla urna, lobortis eu purus ut, malesuada dignissim risus. Donec vel quam quis neque vestibulum lacinia nec ac massa. Curabitur vitae rhoncus erat. Nam a risus sed magna iaculis gravida ut non diam. Mauris non molestie ex. Nam nec volutpat ligula. Duis vitae facilisis diam, et hendrerit lorem. Nullam et luctus metus."
  ]
},
{
  "name": "learn-node",
  "title": "How to Build a Node Server in 10 Minutes",
  "content": [
    "In this article, we 're going to be talking looking at a very quick wayto set up a Node.js server.We 'll be discussing some topics such as ed eget nisi gravida, faucibus risus vitae, sollicitudin lectus. Aliquam mauris leo, pulvinar eget sapien non, mollis pretium enim. Donec mi sapien, aliquam at aliquam at, ullamcorper sit amet risus. Etiam leo justo, imperdiet id sem et, egestas maximus tellus. Nam a efficitur enim, ac ullamcorper elit. Donec nulla urna, lobortis eu purus ut, malesuada dignissim risus. Donec vel quam quis neque vestibulum lacinia nec ac massa. Curabitur vitae rhoncus erat. Nam a risus sed magna iaculis gravida ut non diam. Mauris non molestie ex. Nam nec volutpat ligula. Duis vitae facilisis diam, et hendrerit lorem. Nullam et luctus metus.ed eget nisi gravida, faucibus risus vitae, sollicitudin lectus. Aliquam mauris leo, pulvinar eget sapien non, mollis pretium enim. Donec mi sapien, aliquam at aliquam at, ullamcorper sit amet risus. Etiam leo justo, imperdiet id sem et, egestas maximus tellus. Nam a efficitur enim, ac ullamcorper elit. Donec nulla urna, lobortis eu purus ut, malesuada dignissim risus. Donec vel quam quis neque vestibulum lacinia nec ac massa. Curabitur vitae rhoncus erat. Nam a risus sed magna iaculis gravida ut non diam. Mauris non molestie ex. Nam nec volutpat ligula. Duis vitae facilisis diam, et hendrerit lorem. Nullam et luctus metus."
  ]
},
{
  "name": "my-thoughts-on-resumes",
  "title": "My Thoughts on Resumes",
  "content": [
    "Today is the day I talk about something which scares most people: resumes.In reality, I 'm not sure why people have such a hard time with ed eget nisi gravida, faucibus risus vitae, sollicitudin lectus. Aliquam mauris leo, pulvinar eget sapien non, mollis pretium enim. Donec mi sapien, aliquam at aliquam at, ullamcorper sit amet risus. Etiam leo justo, imperdiet id sem et, egestas maximus tellus. Nam a efficitur enim, ac ullamcorper elit. Donec nulla urna, lobortis eu purus ut, malesuada dignissim risus. Donec vel quam quis neque vestibulum lacinia nec ac massa. Curabitur vitae rhoncus erat. Nam a risus sed magna iaculis gravida ut non diam. Mauris non molestie ex. Nam nec volutpat ligula. Duis vitae facilisis diam, et hendrerit lorem. Nullam et luctus metus.ed eget nisi gravida, faucibus risus vitae, sollicitudin lectus. Aliquam mauris leo, pulvinar eget sapien non, mollis pretium enim. Donec mi sapien, aliquam at aliquam at, ullamcorper sit amet risus. Etiam leo justo, imperdiet id sem et, egestas maximus tellus. Nam a efficitur enim, ac ullamcorper elit. Donec nulla urna, lobortis eu purus ut, malesuada dignissim risus. Donec vel quam quis neque vestibulum lacinia nec ac massa. Curabitur vitae rhoncus erat. Nam a risus sed magna iaculis gravida ut non diam. Mauris non molestie ex. Nam nec volutpat ligula. Duis vitae facilisis diam, et hendrerit lorem. Nullam et luctus metus."
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Tips to Help Build Back Muscle and Definition",
  "title": "Fitness & Health",
  "content": [
    "There is one distinct difference when it comes to the back as opposed to the arms or chest. You can’t see the muscles working unless you’re using mirrors and are at just the right angle.\n\nSo if your goal is to develop your back, then you need to feel the muscles working so you know you’re doing the job properly. Establishing that all-important mind-muscle connection early on in your session means your whole session will be more productive.\n\nSo once you've chugged your preworkout and start to warm up, make sure you feel the back muscles contracting with each rep and feel a stretch when you perform the negative."
  ],
  "id": "jOBJcGY"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your image the json file is one level above, try:

```
import allarticles from '../data.json'
```

Comment: Nice, you can mark the answer as correct c: